# multiply and summing same named columns based on name in 2 different DF pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

it's easy to multiply 2 columns, but some how my code returns NAN that i don't understand.

so i have these columns in df2 that have the same name also in df1. my goal was to multiply and then sum them together.

```
df1.columns=['ISIN', 'DSCD', 'GEOGN', 'SIC', 'GEOGC', 'COMMONSHARESOUTSTANDING',
       'year', 'date', 'month', 'Mcap', 'TotalAssets', 'NItoCommon',
       'NIbefEIPrefDiv', 'PrefDiv', 'NIbefPrefDiv', 'Sales',
       'GainLossAssetSale', 'PPT', 'LTDebt', 'CommonEquity', 'PrefStock',
       'OtherIncome', 'TotalLiabilities', 'PreTaxIncome', 'IncomeTaxes',
       'OtherTA', 'OtherLiabilities', 'CashSTInv', 'OtherCA', 'OtherCL',
       'TotalDiv', 'Country', 'Industry', 'IsSingleCountry', 'Mcap_w',
       'NItoCommon_w', 'NIbefEIPrefDiv_w', 'PrefDiv_w', 'NIbefPrefDiv_w',
       'Sales_w', 'GainLossAssetSale_w', 'PPT_w', 'LTDebt_w', 'CommonEquity_w',
       'PrefStock_w', 'OtherIncome_w', 'TotalLiabilities_w', 'PreTaxIncome_w',
       'IncomeTaxes_w', 'OtherTA_w', 'OtherLiabilities_w', 'CashSTInv_w',
       'OtherCA_w', 'OtherCL_w', 'TotalDiv_w', 'fair_value', 'month__1',
       'month__2', 'month__3', 'month__4', 'month__5', 'month__6', 'month__7',
       'month__8', 'month__9', 'month__10', 'month__11', 'month__12',
       'constant', 'V'
```

df2 has only one row while the other one is more than one row.

```
df2.columns = ['constant', 'TotalAssets', 'NItoCommon_w', 'NIbefEIPrefDiv_w',
       'NIbefPrefDiv_w', 'Sales_w', 'GainLossAssetSale_w', 'PPT_w', 'LTDebt_w',
       'CommonEquity_w', 'PrefStock_w', 'OtherIncome_w', 'TotalLiabilities_w',
       'PreTaxIncome_w', 'IncomeTaxes_w', 'OtherTA_w', 'OtherLiabilities_w',
       'CashSTInv_w', 'OtherCA_w', 'OtherCL_w', 'TotalDiv_w', 'month__1',
       'month__2', 'month__3', 'month__4', 'month__5', 'month__6', 'month__7',
       'month__8', 'month__9', 'month__10', 'month__11', 'month__12',
       'Country', 'predicted_Mcap']
```

i need to multiply and sum these columns:

```
'TotalAssets', 'NItoCommon_w', 'NIbefEIPrefDiv_w',
       'NIbefPrefDiv_w', 'Sales_w', 'GainLossAssetSale_w', 'PPT_w', 'LTDebt_w',
       'CommonEquity_w', 'PrefStock_w', 'OtherIncome_w', 'TotalLiabilities_w',
       'PreTaxIncome_w', 'IncomeTaxes_w', 'OtherTA_w', 'OtherLiabilities_w',
       'CashSTInv_w', 'OtherCA_w', 'OtherCL_w', 'TotalDiv_w'
```

my code:

```
#adding a column to df1 to save the result in it. 
    df1['V']=0
    for col in df2.iloc[:,1:20]:        
        df1['V']+=df1[col]*df2[col]
```

but the result is all NAN which is strange for me.

Comment: please provide your complete code and a reproducible example of the data. You shouldn't need to loop. Are you sure your indices are common?

Comment: @mozway check my Question again pls

Comment: My guess is why your code is returning all NaN values is because you are trying to multiply columns that have NaN values. When you multiply a NaN value by any other value, the result will be NaN.

Comment: @DevamSanghvi  the indexes don't match. 
df2 has only one row while df1 has many rows

Comment: @mozway ...............

Comment: @Mostafa this is not a minimal reproducible example, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464) how to do it. Ideally only a few **dummy** rows/cols and the **data** (not just the column names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for col in co:
    df_Ger_2015_V['V']+=df_Ger_2015_V[col]*co[col].values[0]
```